# CarouFredSel: scroll not working properly with html content

Tags: caroufredsel

So, when I have some items with *html content* in it, and the fx = scroll, direction = left, the first item scrolls left, the container remains empty, then quickly the second item appears. 
If I use images only, one image is one scrollable item, the items follow each other smoothly, so when the first item moves left, right after the second item also comes in from the right side. 
Any idea what should I set, to make the plugin work properly? 
My guess is its something with the width settings of an item, but I tried several settings, no one was good.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your item is to big for the container? or someting with position absolute/relative? Coudl you show me some of your code (and images/div sizes?)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (in stackoverflow). I have to use float:left on the div elements I want to scroll. Now they follow nicely each other.

Answer (score 0):

@subdesign,
As nicely quoted by @RunningFusion may your item be too big for the container.
Try width: "100%" instead of specifying the width in px.